# Call to a member function saveContact() on boolean - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload contacts to a group/category using an excel sheet. Now i am able to upload the contacts but i am not able to assign the groups to each contact.

I have a many to many relation for groups and contacts but after uploading the sheet, the contacts are saved correctly but the pivot table isn't updated with the contacts and their groups they belong to.

I get the error

> > Call to a member function saveContact() on boolean on this line  $customer->saveGroup($request->get('group'));

`$customer->saveGroup($request->get('group'));` retrieves the id of the selected group for the uploaded contacts..

How can i get this done?

**Controller**

```
 public function importCustomer(Request $request)
        {
           if($request->file('imported-file'))
           {
                     $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();

                     $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader)
                     {
                        $reader->calculate(false);

                     })->get();

               if(($request->file('imported-file')->getClientOriginalExtension()) != 'xlsx')
               {
                   return redirect('/customer/view')->with('error','File Format may not be supported');
               }

               else{

               if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
               {
                 foreach ($data->toArray() as $row)
                 {
                   if(!empty($row))
                   {
                     $dataArray[] =
                     [
                       'name' => array_get($row, 'name'),
                     ];
                   }
               }

               if(isset($row['phone']) == 0)
               {
                   return redirect('/customer/view')->with('error','Failed to upload file');
               }

               //  if(!empty($dataArray))
               else
               {
                 $customer = Customer::insert($dataArray);
                 $customer->saveContact($request->get('group'));

        }
```

Comment: Now which one is it, saveContact or saveGroup? And have you researched what this error message means in general, and what therefor your next debugging steps should be right now? If not, please do so.

Comment: @CBroe, method cannot be applied in that way..The general meaning. I am actually trying to get how this could be done.  question edited

Comment: No, that is not the meaning of this error. It means that you tried to call a method of an object, but that “object” isn’t actually one, but (most likely) simply null or false, because something went wrong earlier in your code already. `var_dump($customer);`

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks for the knowledge. when i do `var_dump($customer);` i get `bool(true)` but then the customers in the excel file are saved into the customer table in the database

Comment: Sounds like `Customer::insert` only returns a boolean then, and not an actual Customer object instance - so your code simply doesn’t make sense in that place.